# Is it possible to hide lost+found?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, storage, files

Given a partition intended solely for storing music, video and so-on, is it possible to hide the lost+found directory?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a subdirectory in that filesystem and share/symlink *that* instead of the filesystem root directory.

It's a bad idea to remove the lost+found directory. When recovering, fsck needs an existing multi-sector directory in which to create directory entries for lost files. If there is no lost+found directory, then it has to create one, potentially overwriting data.

Comment: Any sources on that?

Comment: By "sources on that" I assume you mean references? It's not mentioned in any manpages that I can find, but it's mentioned here (thanks, Google): http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec1fsck_lostfound.html

Comment: Real bad idea to remove it.  FSCK will recreate, but as said above potentially causing more damage.

Answer (score 13):

For Gnome2/Mate Nautilus/Caja based desktops, create a file called `.hidden` in the root folder of the drive.

Edit the contents to read:

```
lost+found
```

Nautilus will now hide the lost+found folder if you refresh.  Press 'ctrl-h' to toggle the hidden items visible/invisible.

Comment: Too bad this doesn't seem to work for KDE's Dolphin or even Thunar. However, Thunar hides lost+found by default since it's a system folder, it seems

Comment: @ManuJärvinen What is system folder supposed to mean? As far as the kernel is concerned `lost+found` is an ordinary directory just like any other directory. It is only `fsck` which has a need for this specific directory name. Any other tool treating that name special only does so to match the convention used by `fsck`.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ ls --ignore=lost+found
```

So make that an alias

```
$ alias ls='ls --ignore=lost+found'
```

With the updated ls that is part of GNU coreutils 8.15

re: http://www.askapache.com/linux-unix/bash_profile-functions-advanced-shell.html

Answer (score 5):

Nautilus (and Konq?) will interpret a .hidden file in a directory as a list of files to hide. Otherwise, as others have suggested, use XFS or ReiserFS.

Answer (score 4):

No. But you can delete it (it'll be recreated at the next fsck), or you can use a different file system which doesn't need a lost+found. ext2/3 does.

Comment: Yeah, but you could have a script that deletes it after fsck runs. I don't really know what the point of this would be though.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is only the fsck command, which need the lost+found directory. The file system itself doesn't need it. I couldn't find any mention of the lost+found directory within the file system source code. From the file system's point of view, it is no different from all other directories.

Comment: Really, really bad advice. It is a special directory because http://serverfault.com/a/9909/2101

Answer (score 3):

At least in Ubuntu just change the owner of the directory to root

```
sudo chown -R root:root '/media/user/device/lost+found'
```

that's it.

Comment: works on Thunar, thks

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 2):

Lost+Found is where FSCK is going to deposit bits of files that it was able to recover if your file system is damaged. If the directory is currently empty, you are safe to just delete it.

FSCK (I believe) will re-create it if it has anything that needs to be put there.

Not sure why the presence of that directory is problematic for you, though?

Answer (score 1):

```
rmdir lost+found
```

Answer (score -1):

No. It can't be hidden because under UNIX os's, only files that begin with a period are hidden from a standard view.